# rewriteRule (from Nested Paths For WPMU)

Tags: mod-rewrite, wordpress

I would like to do this

```
example.org/blogname1
example.org/departments/blogname2
example.org/departments/blogname3
example.org/services/blogname3
```

and follow this tutorial http://maisonbisson.com/post/14052/wordpress-hacks-nested-paths-for-wpmu-blogs/

Here is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp-folder/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?/(.*\.php)$ /wp-folder/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Now my problem is to rewrite `http://example.org/wp-admin/network/*` to `http://example.org/wp-folder/wp-admin/network/*`

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with

```
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
#RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin/network.*$ $1wp-folder/wp-admin/network/ [R=301,L]
```